# How to Change the iMessages Conference Hostname in Maverics (Mountion Lion) Server

Tags: mac-osx-server, xmpp

I was running a iChat Server success on Snow Leopard Server.

Connections were running for:
ichat.myservername.com

And the conference server was:
conference.ichat.myservername.com

I have new machine with Maverics server installed.

I have DNS running on the box that properly maps my hostname name (ichat.servername.com) to my internal IP (172.16.1.50).
I have the DNS properly registered externally at my provider for the external IP of the gateway.

My chat server is properly working using:
ichat.myservername.com

But my server has set the conferencing server name to:
rooms.myservername.local

Users inside my network can set that for their conference server it all works well, but how do I change configuration to use the standard:
conference.ichat.myservername.com

I've noticed that /Library/Server/Messages/Config/Rooms.plist

has:
domain
myservername.local
name
rooms

But if I change those settings the Jabber server goes into an infinite loop on startup with "connection closed"

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem.  Not exactly as I'd hope.

1) I made sure that my hostname was properly configured in server config.

2) Shutdown Jabber:
serveradmin stop jabber

3) Rebuilt config files from source:
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/copy_message_server_con fig_files.sh

4) Edit Rooms.plist
/Library/Server/Messages/Config/Rooms.plist

Change the name to conference:
        name
        conference

I also needed to fix my host name in two other files:

5) Edit SM:
/Library/Server/Messages/Config/jabberd/sm.xml

ichat.myservername.com

6) Edit C2S
/Library/Server/Messages/Config/jabberd/c2s.xml:

ichat.myservername.com

7) Restart the server:
sudo serveradmin start jabber

All looks good at this point.